# how can I init an arrayList of say 100 cells and then put a value in the 50th cell

Tags: java, list, arraylist

how can I init an arrayList of say 100 cells

and then put a value in the 50th cell?

```
    completeRoutingResponses = new ArrayList<>(100);
    completeRoutingResponses.add(50, routingResponse);/
```

throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 50, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:661)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:473)
```

**Update**

I used arrayList because I wanted to merge completeRoutingResponses easily

and I have thought to use completeRoutingResponses.addAll(otherCompleteRoutingResponses)

Comment: If you know you'll need exactly 100 cells, why not create an array? `Response[] responses = new Response[100]; responses[pos] = routingResponse;`

Comment: @Andreas I agree with Andreas. Not sure what you want to do. Be more specific

Comment: What is in the cells before you put something there?

Comment: Why is `relativePosition = 151` when you want `50`?

Comment: @Andreas Stole the words from my mouth about 151 vs 50.
Also, I think he's asking a more hypothetical question rather than a strictly 100 cell item, though I may be wrong. Long story short, Check your relativePosition value, Elad. That may be your problem

Comment: I used arrayList because I wanted to merge completeRoutingResponses easily

and I have thought to use completeRoutingResponses.addAll(otherCompleteRoutingResponses)

Comment: That makes even less sense. Why do you want to add something at the index of 50, and why don' t you show the actual exception you get? Clearly the code you have written will throw an exception with the index being 50. What do you want to be in the 50 previous elements of the List?

Comment: I want to have 100 nulls and then put a value in 50th index

Comment: Then you have to fill the list with nulls, as posted in the answer below. You will also have to use set and not add.

Comment: and merging two arrays with for loop? or more elegant solution?

Comment: What do you mean by merging? As in an add all, or fill in the missing values?

Comment: i meant contacting array-c = array-a followed by array-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only set a value, or insert a value which was there previously.  The pattern I use is

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public void set(int index, String s) {
    while(list.size() <= index) list.add(null);
    list.set(index, s);
}
```

The same applied to add. You can't insert a value which didn't exists previously.

Note: your error says you are trying to insert `151` not `50`

---

As @MickMnemonic points out, having to fill and array will `null` isn't great either. It is more likely what you should be doing is using a Map

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

public void set(int index, String s) {
    map.put(index, s);
}
```

No need to pad `null` to insert a value.

Comment: Yuck, no-one likes an array list with `null` elements.

Comment: @MickMnemonic no but you have to put something and empty string could just hide a problem.

Comment: @MickMnemonic On second thought, using a `Map` would avoid the need for `null`s

Comment: I don't know why anyone would use an idiom like this. If you need a fixed-size container, you can use an array; you even get `null`s for free.

Comment: @MickMnemonic It doesn't look that fixed given the OP is add (inserting) to index 151 out of 100, but it's hard to tell if this was intended or a bug.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I like how you take both sides of the issue "No one likes a list with nulls, us an array so it is full of nulls." Also note that your 'idiom like this' follows his suggestion of using a map. Are you saying the OP should not use a Map? A Map will also give you nulls for free, and no nulls if you don't need them, and it works with generics.

Comment: @matt, I don't really understand your comment. My point was that when using collections (dynamic data structures), you want to avoid `null` elements, because they are error-prone and rarely even make sense from a domain-logic perspective: adding a `null` means that you're adding nothing. Arrays are a bit different because client code can/should expect that some values are uninitialized. The safest choice would be to use `Optional` elements if you want to provide sane absence-semantics.

Comment: My comment was about the `null`-filling idiom.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I should have been clearer, but you figured it out anyway. I was pointing out both the List and Array are full of nulls so why is one better than the other. And clarification for the idom, it seemed like you were referring to the Map, but that didn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like relativePosition is starting at 101 then you're adding 50 to it.  Start it at 0 instead.

Answer (score 0):

The capacity of an array list is not the same as its size.

The size is the number of elements in the list, the capacity is how much space is allocated. A place in the array list is not addressable until the size is at least that large.

If you were to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
   completeRoutingResponses.add(i);
}
```

Then you can place an item at index 50.